# Emacs over SSH on Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, emacs

I'm trying to get Emacs to work over SSH under Windows (both client and server). With Emacs 23.2 (downloaded from the GNU FTP), [SUA](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779522(WS.10).aspx) as SSH server and [Bitvise](http://www.bitvise.com/tunnelier) as SSH client, when I run './emacs.exe -nw' I get "standard input is not a tty".

It says [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PuTTY#toc5) that this also doesn't work on a cygwin server, and [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/cygwin@sources.redhat.com/msg01421.html) is an old thread (2000) discussing the same (or very similar) issue.

Has anyone got this to work?

Answer (score 1):

You may use one of the following application to get the xWindows emulator in your windows:

- http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/
- http://connectivity.opentext.com/products/exceed.aspx

When using Exceed all you have to do is mark a checkbox "Enable X11 forwarding" in your Putty when connecting to ssh. Then simply type "emacs" while in console and you will get the Emacs running in a GUI in your Windows. I did not use Xming but I suspect it should work in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks, but I only wanted a console, not a GUI...

Comment: Right, I assumed that if it should work over ssh and in Windows then it's a GUI question. Anyway, hope it can help someone in future.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using dokan on your client and just accessing the files "locally" through that?

http://dokan-dev.net/en/download/

Comment: Dokan seems to be having some issues currently ( http://dokan-dev.net/en/2011/01/12/dokan-sshfs-0-6-0-released/ ), plus it would run locally which I guess would be pretty slow...

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the OpenSSH server that's included with Windows 10 and connecting over PuTTY.  That gives me a command prompt on the Windows box.  Then I installed emacs from https://github.com/zklhp/emacs-w64/

It hangs if run as `emacs` but works as `emacs -nw`.  However the cursor position is not reliably updated.  You can move left and right (whether with right-arrow or C-f) and the cursor stays at the same place until you type some text.